# What happens to leftover money in a 529 College Savings Plans?

Tags: united-states, 529-plan

Assuming a child goes to college and everything is paid from a 529 college savings plan. Once that child graduates and there's leftover money in the savings account, what can be done with that money? Assuming there are no more educational expenses to be paid for.

Comment: @HartCO I don't think my question is a dupe. The other question is about over funding. I'm asking about what happens to the left over money after the student finishes his/her educational plans.

Comment: That is what they meant by overfunding

Comment: @mhoran_psprep I'm not sure the answers answer my question. If I had $10 in a 501 account. My child used $8 of it for their education. What can I do with the remaining $2? Does it just sit there?

Comment: The comment to the dupe is probably more useful than the answers: https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/73460/what-is-a-good-strategy-for-an-over-funded-529-account/73461#73461

Comment: @chepner Thank you. That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep If possible, please mark this dupe and link to the question in the comments.